# ag-grid external filter for columns that doesn't exists in the grid (server side model)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using `ag-grid` with `react`.

I have seen the [external filtering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-external/) and worked it out with server side filtering.

But the external filtering is working with columns which exists in the grid, I want to be able to have an external filter for a field that does not exists in the grid.

For example:

My grid has columns: `col1, col2, col3`

And I want to have an external filter for `free text search` or `col4`.

I have made this work with what feels like a `hack` to me, by adding an hidden column to the grid and updating it with `gridApi.setFilterModel(myFilter)` on external filter change.

Tried with react state:

```
function createServerSideDatasource(getData: any) {
return {
  getRows: async function (params: any) {
    const response = await getData(params.request);
    if (response.success) {
      params.success({
        rowData: response.rows,
        rowCount: response.rowCount,
      });
    } else {
      params.fail();
    }
  },
};
}

const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    const dataSource = createServerSideDatasource(getData);
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(dataSource);
};

function getData(request: any){
    //here i don't have access to my component state, only to the initial values
}
```